# Static readonly string arrays

Tags: c#

I am using static readonly string arrays in my web application. 
Basically array is having error codes and i have kept all similar error codes in one array and checking this array instead of checking each one in different constant string.

like

```
public static readonly string[] myarray = string[] {"232132132","31232132","123123123"}
```

Please let me know is there any harm in using static readony string arrays ?

Note : I am not facing any error, wanted to know is there any harm or performance issue for using like this?

Comment: I can't tell what you're asking, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: sorry for confusing you guys i have updated the question

Answer (score 18):

Try something like this instead:

```
public static readonly ReadOnlyCollection<string> ErrorList = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(
  new string[] {
    "string1",
    "string2",
    "stringn",
  }
);
```

You'll need to `include` the namespace `System.Collections.ObjectModel` in order to expose this object.  ReadOnlyCollection only implements as getter and your array content cannot be changed.

Comment: public static readonly List<string> ErrorList = new List<string>(
            new string[] {
                "string1",
                "string2",
                "stringn",
            }
        );

Answer (score 6):

As Ben mentions, your array is still modifiable. It can't be changed to another array but the elements within it can be easily replaced. As an alternative you can make the array field private and expose it in a public property like so:

```
public class MyClass {

    private static readonly string[] myArray = { ... };
    private static readonly IList<string> myArrayReadOnly = Array.AsReadOnly(myArray);

    public static IList<string> MyArray {
        get {
            return myArrayReadOnly;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why not just go with System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection?

Comment: That's what array.asreadonly returns. But it's not ideal to expose in a public API.

Answer (score 5):

Well, you should know that it is only the array reference that is readonly, not the array content.  So if the array is public (and it sounds like it is), any part of the program could overwrite any or all of the messages, the only thing not possible is resizing the array.

Does that meet your definition of "harm"?

Comment: Yeah , yes thats correct i am making sure no place values of these references get modified . i have taken care for that 
My concern is it good approach ? or can i implement in better way ?

Comment: @prakash: I think what Ben is saying is your array values can be overwritten in which case you haven't taken care of protecting them. A different implementation will be needed instead of an array.

Answer (score -1):

Kivin has a good idea.

You might see if constants in a static class would suit your needs better.