# Can I put readonly strings in an array to iterate over?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, initialization

I have a lot of strings for a lot of headers of my table, like:

```
private readonly string headerOne = translateIfNeeded("headerOne");
private readonly string headerTwo = translateIfNeeded("headerTwo");
private readonly string headerThree = translateIfNeeded("headerThree");
private readonly string headerFour = translateIfNeeded("headerFour");
```

Got around 30 of these.

Can I simply group them into an array, so I can later easily iterate over them? Tried to put the following right below my string, but it won't let me;

```
private readonly string[] headers = { headerOne, headerTwo };
private readonly string[] headers = new string[]{ headerOne, headerTwo };
```

Says something about "A field initializer cannot reference the non-static Field [...] headerOne".

Comment: `private static readonly string[] headers = { headerOne, headerTwo };`

Comment: Same error message. That would have been too easy, wouldn't it?

Comment: You could initialize your headers array in the constructor: `headers = new string[] { headerOne, headerTwo }` and declaring the member variable simply via `private readonly string[] headers;`

Comment: Thought about that too, but then my constructor would be really fat :(

Comment: That's true, the constructor would be cluttered. If you only use the header variables, you could use reflection to read all variables via `this.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)`, initialize it with your translate function and add the header to a list

Comment: this is the best answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2395337/4827151

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Dictionary<int, string>` or  `Dictionary<string, string>`:

```
Dictionary<string, string> headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
headers.Add("headerOne", translateIfNeeded("headerOne"));
headers.Add("headerTwo", translateIfNeeded("headerTwo"));
headers.Add("headerThree", translateIfNeeded("headerThree"));
headers.Add("headerFour", translateIfNeeded("headerFour"));
```

You can iterate over it or (standard way) access the value by the key:

```
string headerTwo = headers["headerTwo"];
```

If you need a readonly dictionary, there's one since  version 4.5:

[`ReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>` Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712875(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Beautiful idea. Will mark as solution if no answer to this particular question emerges in time.

Comment: The readonly thing actually is for more const-ness, having the system order the stuff neatly internally. AFAIK constants get a seperate memory area. Any tips for optimization here?

Comment: You shouldn't worry about these micro-optimisations. If the field is an unchanging constant then use `const;` If it's not, don't. In this case it can't be a constant.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Static readonly string arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2395337/6741868), even though it uses static:

```
public readonly ReadOnlyCollection<string> headers = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(
  new string[] {
    headerOne,
    headerTwo,
    headerThree,
  }
);
```

For reference: [ReadOnlyCollection(T) Class (System.Collections.ObjectModel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474(v=vs.110).aspx) and [C# ReadOnlyCollection Tips - Dot Net Perls](https://www.dotnetperls.com/readonlycollection)

Answer (score 0):

You can define a List add all the headers and easliy iterate over them, Simple Example:

```
        List<string> headersList = new List<string>();
        headersList.AddRange(new string[] { headerOne, headerTwo, headerThree, headerFour });

        foreach (string header in headersList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(header);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```